# Pass concatenated string parameter in informix trigger

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, informix

I have a trigger which passes some parameters to a procedure and invoke it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_ins INSERT ON mytable
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW(EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ins("mytable", new.id, 'I'));
```

Is there any way I can pass concatenated char as the second parameter to the above procedure call?

I need this because I may need to allow these parameters:

```
"id = " . new.id
"field1 =" . new.field1 . "and field2 = " . new.field2
```

Comment: Don't you have them available to you in their raw form, i.e. `sp_ins("mytable", new.id, new.field1, new.field2, ...)` ? Why concatenate them?

Comment: I wanted the procedure to accept it as 1 argument regardless of the table. For example, for one table, it would be just one column `id = new.id`. For another table, it would be 2 columns - `field1 = new.field1 and field2 = new.field2`. Basically I want that argument to be a where condition string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression this is to produce some sort of shared audit or logging table. You'll obviously need to define the `TRIGGER` on a per-table basis, so with each declaration, you nominate the relevant fields, e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_ins INSERT ON mytable
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW(EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ins("mytable",
    "field1 = " || new.field1 || " and field2 = " || new.field2, 'I'));
```

But it looks and feels a bit clumsy. I can't help thinking this is an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) of some sort.

---

**UPDATE**

*(Following comment 'need not be `where_clause`')*

Well, the obvious answer is to make sure every table has a simple, single surrogate key column, that can be treated like a ROWID.

That's more easily said than done when you have an existing model, of course. If that's not possible, then what you want is a representation of your compound key in a manner that can be parsed later if need be. Exactly how you do that depends on how you intend to parse it: programmatically or through preconstructed SQL fragment as you first proposed. The former is more controllable, but won't produce 'injectable' SQL fragments:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ins("mytable",
    "<field1>" || NVL(new.field1,"") || "</field1>" ||
    "<field2>" || NVL(new.field2,"") || "</field2>",
    "I");
```

...is one way of doing it. You can do the SQL fragment approach, it's just the construction is very messy, as shown above. For example, if field1 is a string, the SQL is already broken, and you need to do something like this:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ins("mytable", 
    "field1 " || NVL('= "'||new.field1||'"','IS NULL') || ' AND ' ||
    "field2 " || NVL('= "'||new.field2||'"','IS NULL'),
    "I")
```

... and you can be sure that sooner or later you'll run into an Irish problem where a name like `O'Malley` or `Sylvester "Sly" Stallone` breaks those embedded quotes. There's no elegant solution because it's an inelegant thing you're trying to do.

Informix provides [out-of-the-box audit features](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.secnode.doc/secnode.htm), and [ways and means of exploring the logical logs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0350.htm). I can't help thinking you'd be better off exploring those.

Comment: Yes, each table will have separate trigger which would pass different number of fields. All triggers would call the same procedure.

Comment: Is my answer what you were after? Be aware that you'll run into issues with this approach if field1 or field2 can be validly NULL. Be warned...

Comment: Field values cannot be empty, because these would be part of unique index

Comment: That's sort of my point - a unique constraint can still allow a NULL value - you need to have a NOT NULL constraint as well.

Comment: Do you have any other elegant solution for my problem? I have triggers for each table which would invoke a procedure which would insert the `where clause` in a metatable which would uniquely identify the row. It need not be `where clause`, rather any information to uniquely identify a row in the table so that I can retrieve it later.